# Can I say that a straight line have infinite radius?

Tags: geometry

Can I say that a straight line has infinite radius?

Comment: You can say anything you want.

Comment: It is somewhat more interesting to observe that the collection of lines and circles in the plane is the orbit of any single line or circle under the group action by [Möbius transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A straight line has zero curvature, hence an infinite *radius of curvature*. From this point of view, it would make sense to say that a straight line has infinite radius.

Comment: +1. This point of view is helpful in many cases, one including the moebius transformation in the study of complex functions. Sometimes a "generalized circle" is used as a term for something which is either a circle or a line.